# Is it possible to store spinning text in XML format?

Tags: c#, xml, string, parsing

I want to implement this feature in C#.

I have a sentence in *spin* format :

*{My name is PapyRef and I am a {member|user|visitor} on this {forum|website|site} and I am loving it | I am admin and I am a {supervisor|admin|moderator} on this {forum|website|site} and I am loving it}*

I want to generate an xml document that contains this spinning text.
For example:

```
<SpinItem>
    <Item>
       <Text>My name is PapyRef and I am a</Text>
    </Item>
    <SpinItem>
       <Text>member</Text>
       <Text>user</Text>
       <Text>visitor</Text>
    </SpinItem>
    <SpinItem>
       <Text>forum</Text>
       <Text>website</Text>
       <Text>site</Text>
    </SpinItem>
    <Item>
       <Text> and I am loving it </Text>
    </Item>
</SpinItem>
<SpinItem>
    <Item>
       <Text> I am admin and I am a </Text>
    </Item>
    <SpinItem>
        <Text>supervisor</Text>
        <Text>admin</Text>
        <Text>moderator</Text>
     </SpinItem>
     <SpinItem>
        <Text>forum</Text>
        <Text>website</Text>
        <Text>site</Text>
     </SpinItem>
     <Item>
        <Text> and I am loving it</Text>
     </Item>
</SpinItem>
```

I want to convert spinning text (italicized text) into XML format.

How can do this in C#?

Comment: "spinning" in what context? Web? HTML? SVG? WebGL? Fill in some blanks here.

Comment: After addressing @ReacherGilt 's points, please tell us what you have tried. Where are you getting stuck? Do you know how to read XML files? stackoverflow is generally for questions that go beyond "write it for me".

Comment: Are you saying that you want C# to convert that italicized text there into the XML you're showing?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The desired result looks overly complicated: the whole point of XML is that you can *mix* text with data in a semi-structured schema. You should omit all your `<Text>` nodes, they add nothing. Also, the `<SpinItem>`s don’t work the way you want them to. You need to replace the `<Text>` nodes inside by dedicated `<Item>` nodes, otherwise the schema cannot distinguish between concatenation and alternation of text.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes.
@ Konrad Rudolph. OK. I Update my example.

Comment: @PapyRef You’ve made the XML *more* complex instead of less and you haven’t corrected the mistaks in the schema.

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph I do not understand where is the error. Can you give an example of simplification and correct error

Answer (score 0):

[Top-down parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing) should help you. Here are few similar questions:

- [Implementing a Top Down Parser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097383/implementing-a-top-down-parser-in-c-sharp)
- [Top-Down Parsing Implement in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936500/top-down-parsing-implement-in-c-sharp)